Trying to locate a specific acorn door latch that needs to be replaced
I just purchased my home and there are a few doors that use wrought-iron spade latches around the house. One of them is on the door to the basement utility room and is missing the thumb piece. I'm hoping to replace it, but I can't find a match based on an image search; only similar ones that aren't quite the same. Does anyone know where I might be able to find one of these?
Things that are different than others that I'm finding:
These have three screws in the top spade.
The screw heads are square.
The bottom acorn is about 1/3 the size of the top acorn.
It appears that the hinges are from the same manufacturer. They have the same screws and texture.
The bottom spade is much smaller.
Pictures are here. Thank you!

You might have to go with the similar ones.  Door hardware is almost the same as cars, they change designs every year.  Can spend time searching for the exact ones, or replace with similar ones.  Exact ones might be the same as a needle in a hay stack.  Buying a few similar ones might be less time, for them to match.
